# Serial Communications delay

Tags: arduino, serial, matlab, simulink

Hopefully this is more of an electrical engineering question than a MATLAB question, but I don't understand a system response I'm getting.
I recently got 2 Arduino Due's and configured 1 in MATLAB Simulink to be a pulse signal generator and the other to loop the signal back:

[image]

[image]

I have the signal being generated as sample based with the sample time set at .01 seconds which also means the serial read, write and scope block have the same sample time. The solver setting for this board is also set at .01 seconds. I set the pulse widths and period length to the appropriate values to get a 1Hz signal (50 pulse width and 100 period width).

For the first check I set the loop-back board with the same sample time settings but have it running in external mode. I loaded both models to the boards, ran the loop-back board and started the generator board. I got an output that showed a .01 second difference between signals which I figured to be due to the .01 sample time of the loop-back board.

The next check I did was set all the sample time settings (solver, serial read, serial write) on the loop-back board to .1 seconds. I loaded both models on the boards again and ran the loop-back then started the generator and still got .01 seconds. I figured with that a factor of ten less samples per second would cause a greater delay but I'm not sure if its my lack of knowledge/understanding in serial comms, arduino or matlab causing confusion. Even if what I'm getting is expected... still not sure why.

Is the delay a factor of sampling time or intrinsic to the circuit? I understand not meeting the nyquist rate can result in missed data but it my case the the graph was just shifted.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Both actual and USB virtual serial interfaces are sources of delay, but it sounds like you may have something else going on.  Desktop computers arent really meant for precise timing but there sounds like a lot not well understood in your setup even if there were no OS latency - it may simply be doing what it was designed to, outside your intent or awareness.